# Date fields coming null from view, not manipulating them at all

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, oracle11g

so I am working in a Spring MVC project where I have this class with a few Date fields and I am creating a CRUD for it. Problem is, I read an instance of the class from the database and then send it to the view for editing, and although I am not manipulating any of the Date fields, only the strings, when I collect the object using a post form, the Date fields come as null even though they came from the database with a value and I sent them to the view with that value.

The class:

```
package com.sophos.mat.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

@Entity
@Table(name="T_PROYECTOS")
public class Proyecto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="IN_PROYECTO")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="SECUENCIA_IN_PROYECTO")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SECUENCIA_IN_PROYECTO", sequenceName="SECUENCIA_IN_PROYECTO", allocationSize=1, initialValue= 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="VC_NOMBRE")
    @Length(max = 50, message = "El campo no puede exceder los 50 caracteres")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="VC_DESCRIPCION")
    @Length(max = 200, message = "El campo no puede exceder los 200 caracteres")
    private String descripcion;

    @Column(name="VC_CODIGO_SOPHOS")
    @Length(max = 20, message = "El campo no puede exceder los 20 caracteres")
    private String codigoSophos;

    @Column(name="DT_FECHACREACION")
    private Date fechaCreacion;

    @Column(name="VC_USUARIOACTUALIZACION")
    private String usuarioActualizacion;

    @Column(name="DT_FECHAACTUALIZACION")
    private Date fechaActualizacion;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public String getCodigoSophos() {
        return codigoSophos;
    }
    public void setCodigoSophos(String codigoSophos) {
        this.codigoSophos = codigoSophos;
    }
    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return fechaCreacion;
    }
    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }
    public String getUsuarioActualizacion() {
        return usuarioActualizacion;
    }
    public void setUsuarioActualizacion(String usuarioActualizacion) {
        this.usuarioActualizacion = usuarioActualizacion;
    }
    public Date getFechaActualizacion() {
        return fechaActualizacion;
    }
    public void setFechaActualizacion(Date fechaActualizacion) {
        this.fechaActualizacion = fechaActualizacion;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
package com.sophos.mat.controller;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.sophos.mat.beans.Proyecto;
import com.sophos.mat.services.IProyectoService;

@Controller
public class ProyectoController {


    @Autowired
    private IProyectoService proyectoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editarproyecto/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editarProyectoGet(ModelMap model, @PathVariable long id){
        try {
            Proyecto proyectoData = proyectoService.buscarProyectoPorId(id);
            model.put("proyectoData", proyectoData);
            return "editarproyecto";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/proyectos";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/editarproyecto/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editarProyectoPost(ModelMap model, @PathVariable long id, @ModelAttribute("proyectoData")@Valid Proyecto proyectoData, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "editarproyecto";
        }
        try{

            proyectoData.setFechaActualizacion(new Date());
            proyectoService.actualizarProyecto(proyectoData);
            return "redirect:/proyectos";

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/proyectos";
        }
    }

    public IProyectoService getProyectoService() {
        return proyectoService;
    }

    public void setProyectoService(IProyectoService proyectoService) {
        this.proyectoService = proyectoService;
    }
}
```

And the view: editarproyecto.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri= "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>>Nuevo Proyecto</title>
        <style>
            .error { color: red; }
        </style>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Nuevo Proyecto</h1>
        <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="proyectoData">
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Nombre proyecto:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="nombre"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:errors path="nombre" cssClass="error"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Descripción
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="descripcion"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:errors path="descripcion" cssClass="error"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Cód. Sophos
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="codigoSophos"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:errors path="codigoSophos" cssClass="error"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Usuario que actualiza
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="usuarioActualizacion"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:errors path="usuarioActualizacion" cssClass="error"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
        </form:form>
        <a href="<c:url value="proyectos"/>">Proyectos</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When processing POST, I get an exception from hibernate telling me that I'm trying to update to NULL the column 'DT_FECHACREACION' corresponding to the class field 'fechaCreacion'. As a temporary fix, I had to add in the POST method a query to the database to reset 'fechaCreacion' back to its previous value which I don't want to change and then update the entity with the rest of the captured values. That works but is ugly af and adds extra and unwanted overhead. My database is Oracle 11g. Thanks in advance folks!

PD: Very newbie spring developer, am in my internship and trying my best to get a full contract when the internship is over :D so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the service you have to control which fields you return to the view.

```
 Proyecto proyectoData = proyectoService.buscarProyectoPorId(id);
```

You can omit fields your DAO is returning with @JsonIgnore annotation.

```
 ....
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;


 @Entity
 @Table(name="T_PROYECTOS")
 public class Proyecto implements Serializable{
     ...

    @JsonIgnore
    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
         return fechaCreacion;
    }

     ....
 }
```

Comment: Would it prevent me from being able to display that date in a future view? Also, what should I add to my pom to be able to use the annotation? I can't seem to find the jar in the mave repo.